# Logstash config, "if string contains..."

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

So, let's assume that I have a portion of a log line that looks something like this:

```
GET /restAPI/callMethod1/8675309
```

The GET matches a http method, and get's extracted, the remainder matches a URI, and also gets extracted.  Now in the logstash config let's assume that I wanted to do something like this...

```
if [METHOD] == "GET" {
    if [URI] (CONTAINS <--Is there a way to do this?) =="restAPI/callMethod1"{
        ....
```

Is there some way to do this?  If so how would I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can achieve it simply by using the `=~` (regexp) operator like this (see [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals)):

```
if [METHOD] == "GET" {
  if [URI] =~ /restAPI\/callMethod1/ {
     ...
```