# PySpark based web request parsing using conditional multi-regex

Tags: regex, parsing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pattern-matching

After [understating log concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apaches-access-log) I'm working on web request logs and try to match some keywords inside of string of those logs are their method is [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491219/python-parse-getpost-path-from-access-logs) and I also reviewed [pythonic log parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775467/python-parsing-web-access-logs) and related post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266407/how-can-i-write-conditional-regex-replace-in-pyspark) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623501/conditional-regex-parsing).

let's assume that I have a portion of a log line that looks something like this:

```
"GET /pas/public/ping?pas-client=007 HTTP/1.1"
```

the full log is:

```
[10/Oct/2021:05:45:20 +0000] SsAzyfdtrfdV1GKU7+Q== user_Zwfikdlo5CgOT0Loq8g== "GET /pas/public/ping?pas-client=007 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-b" 53b 5ms "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)" qFhyYRqbqtsM7tA== 50001 - -
```

So I tried to use a regex can match with some part of API or query path (means ) before ? mark or (URL parameters). I want to check the events in spark dataframe which has single column `raw` and if it was *GET* http method then match it with `/ping?`. if it was the case I create column name Type and label it ping in from of that event as below and if it was not I label it *POST*:

| raw | Type |
| --- | --- |
| [10/Oct/2021:05:45:20 +0000] SsAzyfdtrfdV1GKU7+Q== user_Zwfikdlo5CgOT0Loq8g== "GET /pas/public/ping?pas-client=007 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-b" 53b 5ms "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)" qFhyYRqbqtsM7tA== 50001 - - | GET_ping |

```py
# parsing df
sdf = (df  
    .withColumn('Type', F
        .when(F.isnull('raw'), '-')
        .when(F.regexp_extract('raw', '(?i)^/ping?$', 0) == F.col('raw'), 'ping') #To specify ping activities
```

So here my problem is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022920/logstash-config-if-string-contains) kind of multi condition regex problem. So how I can create right conditional regex which can match:

- with a word start with `"` following by `space` and it has 3 letters `G` `E` `T`
- with a word start with `/` and ended up with `?` and it has 4 letters `p` `i` `n` `g`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems a bit off. [This](https://regex101.com/r/IR6MMB/1) is my version. You should at least escape the backslashes `\` and the question mark `?` after `ping`.

```py
(df
    .withColumn('type', F
        .when(F.isnull('raw'), '-')
        .when(F.regexp_extract('raw', '(GET).*(\/ping)\?', 0).isNotNull(), 'GET_ping')
        .otherwise('POST')
    )
    .select('type')
    .show()
)
```